# Always open URLs from a pinned tab in a new window

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I want to make sure that all the tabs that I've pinned will stay pinned at the correct page. In Google Chrome, is it possible to prevent the URL of a pinned tab from being changed (so that clicking on any link from a pinned tab will open the link in a new window, instead of changing the pinned tab's URL)? I sometimes navigate to other pages from pinned tabs, thus losing the tab that was supposed to be pinned.

Comment: It appears that this Chrome extension is designed to make links from pinned tabs open in a new window: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-pinnedtab-link/lpjfkobpnfgddkikflgejdgclhpmagha However, I still haven't found a way to make typed URLS open in a new window from pinned tabs.

Comment: Also, here is a relevant discussion on Google Product Forums: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4WSqfjK-Wh0

Comment: The Google Chrome extension that I posted above is the best solution that I've found so far: it works reasonably well.

Comment: I tried that but it was too cluttered. I made one in a few lines: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sticky-pinned-tabs/mjlgfnggkljhiipiiogoengknkfocbkp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply wish to restore pinned tabs when starting up Chrome, simply add the parameter `--pinned-tab-count=5` or any number you prefer. Further details [from this article](http://lifehacker.com/5422014/make-google-chrome-open-with-permanently-pinned-tabs).

If you want to always restore a set of tabs to specific URLs that does not change, a better option is to bookmark that set of tabs. Right-click on any of the tabs, and click on `Bookmark all tabs`. You can also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Restoring the tabs is as easy as right-clicking on the bookmark folder and selecting `Open all bookmarks`.

Another alternative for you to save your browsing session is to use an extension such as [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko), where you can edit individual tabs for your session.

Comment: Also, you can use the Open PinnedTab Link extension to ensure that links from pinned tabs will always open in a new window. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-pinnedtab-link/lpjfkobpnfgddkikflgejdgclhpmagha